# Ruby: Can't Iterate From Time Despite Responding to Succ

Tags: ruby

The Ruby docs for [Range#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Range.html#method-i-each) say

```
The each method can only be used if the begin object of the range supports the succ 
method. A TypeError is raised if the object does not have succ method defined (like 
Float).
```

`Time` does respond to `succ` (even though it's marked as obsolete since Ruby 1.9.2):

```
>> Time.now.succ
(irb):11: warning: Time#succ is obsolete; use time + 1
=> 2021-10-02 14:52:56 -0700
```

However, trying to use `Range#each` when the elements are `Time` objects gives me the `TypeError` the docs mention:

```
t = Time.now
range = (t..t+1)
range.each { |t| p t } # TypeError (can't iterate from Time)
```

I'm trying to determine when it's safe to iterate through a `Range`.  Based on the docs, I had thought checking that its beginning element responds to `succ` was sufficient.  This example suggests that's not quite right.

Do folks have better insight into how to determine this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Based on the docs, I had thought checking that its beginning element responds to `succ` was sufficient.

Unfortunately, the documentation is somewhat incomplete here. It is *not* enough that the beginning element responds to the `succ` message.

The way that [`Range#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-each) iterates is that it first `yield`s the beginning element. Then it sends `succ` to the beginning element and `yield`s the return value of that message send. Then it sends `succ` to *that* element … and so on.

You can think of it something like this:

```ruby
class Range
  def each
    return enum_for(__callee__) { size } unless block_given?

    current = self.begin
    while (current <=> self.end).negative?
      yield current
      current = current.succ
    end

    yield current unless exclude_end?

    self
  end
end
```

So, is not enough that the *beginning* element responds to the `succ` message, but the object returned by that message send also needs to respond to `succ`, and the object returned by sending `succ` to that element as well, and so on.

In addition tho that, all elements also need to respond to `<=>` with the ending element as argument.

> This example suggests that's not quite right.

Since, as you say, `Time#succ` is deprecated, it would *theoretically* be possible that `Range#each` explicitly checks whether the beginning element is an instance of [`Time`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html), and [`raise`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-raise)s a [`TypeError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/TypeError.html) because of the use of a deprecated method. In fact, that is actually what happens in at least some Ruby implementations, see for example in [Rubinius `core/range.rb` lines 109–111](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/range.rb#L109-L111):

> ```ruby
> unless first.respond_to?(:succ) && !first.kind_of?(Time)
>   raise TypeError, "can't iterate from #{first.class}"
> end
> ```

or [TruffleRuby `src/main/ruby/truffleruby/core/range.rb` lines 277–279](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/blob/master/src/main/ruby/truffleruby/core/range.rb#L277-L279):

> ```ruby
> unless first.respond_to?(:succ) && !Primitive.object_kind_of?(first, Time)
>   raise TypeError, "can't iterate from #{first.class}"
> end
> ```

or [JRuby `core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyRange.java` lines 611–613](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyRange.java#L611-L613):

> ```java
> if (!discreteObject(context, begin)) {
>   throw context.runtime.newTypeError("can't iterate from " + begin.getMetaClass().getName());
> }
> ```

in combination with [the definition of `discreteObject` on lines 873–876](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyRange.java#L874):

> ```java
> if (obj instanceof RubyTime) return false;
> ```

or in [YARV `range.c` line 978–981](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_3_0/range.c#L978-L981):

> ```c
> if (!discrete_object_p(beg)) {
>     rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "can't iterate from %s",
>              rb_obj_classname(beg));
> }
> ```

in combination with [the definition of `discrete_object_p` on lines 311–316](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_3_0/range.c#L314):

> ```c
> if (rb_obj_is_kind_of(obj, rb_cTime)) return FALSE; /* until Time#succ removed */
> ```

[Note the comment! Also note that I filed [a bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18237) and [submitted a patch](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/4928/files#diff-3e202665cd48326cc6415f1139a8ec7acd9a1833c51630644b126f49718e6cffL350) that [has already been merged](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/4928#event-5399762080), so what I wrote above is actually no longer true.]

Interestingly, neither [Opal](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/range.rb#L81-L83) nor [IronRuby](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironruby/blob/master/Src/Libraries/Builtins/RangeOps.cs#L502-L504) nor [MRuby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/mrblib/range.rb#L59) check for `Time`. MRuby sticks closely to the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html), which does not specify `Time#succ` (see section 15.2.19.7.23–24), so that makes sense. Both [IronRuby](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironruby/blob/master/Src/Libraries/Builtins/RubyTime.cs#L667-L670) and [Opal](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/time.rb#L375-L381) implement `Time#succ` and don't check for an instance of `Time` in their respective `Range#each` methods, so your code would actually work. (The reason for IronRuby is probably because it never implemented Ruby 1.9.2 completely; not sure about Opal.)

If you are using a recent version of YARV (which is true for the vast majority of Ruby programmers), the answer may actually be much simpler: after being deprecated for 10 years, [`Time#succ`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-subsec) was [removed](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/7817a438eb1803e7b3358f43bd1f38479badfbdc#diff-4d6aa11490d07784e15909bf5081b81052a370b9083a797fae8015cbeb7ee49fL4263-L4295). There *is no `Time#succ` anymore* in recent versions of YARV. (It is likely that other implementors will follow.)

This shows that relying on deprecated methods is dangerous: they might be removed (like what happened in YARV), or they might not exist in the first place (like what happened in MRuby), or they might accidentally work (like in Opal and IronRuby).

> Do folks have better insight into how to determine this?

My approach typically goes something like this:

1. Carefully read and analyze the documentation *for the latest version* on [Ruby-Doc](https://ruby-doc.org/).
2. Carefully read and analyze the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html).
3. Carefully read and analyze the [`ruby/spec`](https://github.com/ruby/spec).
4. Carefully read and analyze any relevant discussions on [Bugs.Ruby-Lang.Org](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/).
5. Write exploratory tests on multiple different versions of multiple different implementations and carefully analyze their results and behavior.
6. Read the relevant parts of the source code of

   - [Rubinius](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/)
   - [Opal](https://github.com/opal/opal/)
   - [TruffleRuby](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/)
   - [JRuby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/)
   - [IronRuby](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironruby/)
   - [MRuby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/)
   - [YARV](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/)
7. Step back, go to sleep, and ignore the problem for at least two days.
8. Start again from step #1 with a fresh head.
9. Discuss the problem with other Ruby developers.
10. Based on those discussions, start again from step #1 with everything I learned from those discussions.
11. Write a question on Stack Overflow, *but do not submit it yet*.
12. Step back, go to sleep, and ignore the problem for at least two days.
13. Submit the question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: The hard-coded "type check" however was not removed. If you create a subclass `class MyTime < Time` which implements `succ`, you still can't use it in a range in Ruby 3.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that the hypothetical type check I invented purely for the sake of this answer *actually* exists? That is funny. Can you point me to it? I can't find it in https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/range.c#L288-L309

Comment: I thought you were being sarcastic :-) Here it is: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_0_2/range.c#L314 (also still in master)

Comment: I added some information about the checks. And realized once again that I very much prefer reading Rubinius, Opal, TruffleRuby, JRuby, and IronRuby over MRuby, and MRuby over YARV (in that order of preference).

Comment: I don't understand why they added an extra check for Time in the first place. The deprecation warning from `Time#succ` would be enough IMO (attempting to use times in a range would generate plenty of warnings).

Comment: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18237

Comment: Many programmers don't read warnings, though, or even know of their existence. (As evidenced by the many SO questions caused by accidental method re-definitions, which could have been solved simply by reading the warnings.)

Comment: I still don’t understand the motivation for this check. What’s so problematic in iterating time ranges in 1-second increments?

Comment: Dunno. [The check is gone](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/4928) now, and [a change to the spec](https://github.com/ruby/spec/pull/852) is in the works.

Comment: Aaaaand [the spec is fixed](https://github.com/ruby/spec/pull/852).