# Minimal interface for Range#include? support

Tags: ruby, range, include, comparable

I'd like to make my yearless dates class play nice with `Range#include?`, [according to the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Range.html#class-Range-label-Ranges+and+User-Defined+Classes), all it has to implement is `<=>`:

```rb
class Count
  include Comparable

  attr_reader :value

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def <=>(other)
    value <=> other.value
  end
end
```

Let's try on Ruby 3.1.1:

```rb
(Count.new(1)..Count.new(5)).include? Count.new(3)
# => in `each': can't iterate from Count (TypeError)
```

I don't get why it's trying to iterate here, `each` should not be necessary to figure out inclusion.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Maybe you want `cover?`. For `include?` you also have to implement `succ`. (as shown in the docs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect or (rather, I suspect) outdated. [`Range#cover?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) works the way you expect [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> ## `cover?(object)` → `true` or `false`
>
> Returns `true` if the given argument is within `self`, `false` otherwise.
>
> With **non-range argument object**, evaluates with **`<=` and `<`**.

The documentation for [`Range#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) contains a somewhat ominous statement [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> If begin and end are numeric, `include?` behaves like `cover?`
>
> […]
>
> But **when not numeric**, the two methods may differ:
>
> ```ruby
> ('a'..'d').include?('cc') # => false
> ('a'..'d').cover?('cc')   # => true
> ```

Here you can see the difference: `Range#cover?` evaluates to `true` because `'a' <= 'cc' && 'cc' <= 'd'`, whereas `Range#include?` evaluates to `false` because `('a'..'d').to_a == ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and thus `('a'..'d').each.include?('cc')` is falsey.

Note that the introductory example using [`Time`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html) still works because [`Time` is explicitly special-cased in the spec](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/range/shared/include.rb#L80-L90).

There *is* [a spec which says both `Range#include?` and `Range#cover?` use `<=>`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/range/shared/cover_and_include.rb#L34-L41), but it is only tested with [`Integer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html)s, for which we know from the ominous documentation above that `Range#include?` and `Range#cover?` behave the same.

There is quite a lot of special-casing going on for `Range`s and it is not the first time this has led to bugs and/or non-intuitive behavior:

- [Ruby: Can't Iterate From Time Despite Responding to Succ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69420562/2988) / [Bug #18237 *Remove unnecessary checks for `Time` in `Range#each` as per the comment*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18237) / https://github.com/ruby/spec/pull/852 / https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/4928
- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18155
- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18577
- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18580
- https://github.com/ruby/dev-meeting-log/blob/master/DevMeeting-2022-02-17.md#bug-18580-rangeinclude-inconsistency-for-beginless-string-ranges-zverok

Personally, I am not a big fan of all this special-casing. I assume it is done for performance reasons, but the way to get better performance is not to add weird special cases to the language specification, it is to *remove* them which makes the language simpler and thus easier to optimize. Or, put another way: at any given point in time, a compiler writer can either spend the time implementing weird special cases or awesome optimizations, but not both. XRuby, Ruby.NET, MacRuby, MagLev, JRuby, IronRuby, TruffleRuby, Rubinius, Topaz, and friends have shown that the way to get high-performance Ruby is a powerful compiler, not weird hand-rolled special-cased C code.

I would [file a bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/HowToReport), if only to get some clarification into the docs and specs.